# Install syslog-ng on RHEL 7

Tags: redhat, syslog-ng

I'm very surprised at how much trouble this is giving me.

I have a RHEL 7 machine I'm trying to install syslog-ng on. I added the EPEL repository, I get the following output:

```
# yum install syslog-ng.x86_64 --enablerepo=epel syslog-ng
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, rhui-lb, search-disabled-repos
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package syslog-ng.x86_64 0:3.5.6-3.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: ivykis >= 0.36.1 for package: syslog-ng-3.5.6-3.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libivykis.so.0(IVYKIS_0.30)(64bit) for package: syslog-ng-3.5.6-3.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libivykis.so.0(IVYKIS_0.29)(64bit) for package: syslog-ng-3.5.6-3.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libnet.so.1()(64bit) for package: syslog-ng-3.5.6-3.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libivykis.so.0()(64bit) for package: syslog-ng-3.5.6-3.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libevtlog.so.0()(64bit) for package: syslog-ng-3.5.6-3.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package eventlog.x86_64 0:0.2.13-4.el7 will be installed
---> Package ivykis.x86_64 0:0.36.2-2.el7 will be installed
---> Package syslog-ng.x86_64 0:3.5.6-3.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libnet.so.1()(64bit) for package: syslog-ng-3.5.6-3.el7.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: syslog-ng-3.5.6-3.el7.x86_64 (dl.fedoraproject.org_pub_epel_7_x86_64_)
           Requires: libnet.so.1()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

As you can see, it is failing on libnet.so.1. I've looked around, and apart from some very old tickets on the RedHat bug tracker, I haven't found any information about this. I can't find this in the RedHat repositories, including EPEL and Fedora. How do I resolve this? Again, I'm very surprised that syslog-ng is so awkward to install in Red Hat, so I am wondering if I'm doing something wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: Or you could just use rsyslog, like the rest of the world.

Comment: Why are you changing the logging subsystem?

Comment: Compatibility with other systems. The details are too complicated to be worth summarizing here. Suffice to say, I need syslog-ng.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure you have the RHEL optional channel enabled. Many packages from EPEL require it. The [process to do this on EC2](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/891363) differs from the [normal process](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/265523).

Do it the easy way with `yum-config-manager`:

```
yum-config-manager --enable rhui-REGION-rhel-server-extras rhui-REGION-rhel-server-optional
```

Or the old-fashioned manual way: edit `/etc/yum.repos.d/redhat.repo` to ensure that these repos are enabled.

Answer (score 1):

libnet.so is [listed as available](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/3/srodzaj/1/search/libnet.so.1()(64bit)) (on rpm search) for CentOS 7 and Scientific Linux 7.  Have you tried installing it from one of those?  Odd that it's not there for RHEL 7.

CentOS 7
`ftp.centos.org/7.1.1503/os/x86_64/Packages/libnet-1.1.6-7.el7.x86_64.rpm`

CentOS 7
`ftp.centos.org/7.2.1511/os/x86_64/Packages/libnet-1.1.6-7.el7.x86_64.rpm`

Scientific Linux 7
`ftp.scientificlinux.org/linux/scientific/7.1/x86_64/os/Packages/libnet-1.1.6-7.el7.x86_64.rpm`

Scientific Linux 7
`ftp.scientificlinux.org/linux/scientific/7.0/x86_64/os/Packages/libnet-1.1.6-7.el7.x86_64.rpm`

Looks like it's the same package for CentOS 7.0, 7.1 and Scientific Linux 7.0, 7.1.  Specifically `libnet-1.1.6-7.el7.x86_64.rpm`